# Most polite, not too formal way to remind one's elder of something?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

I am aware of a polite way to remind my elder, say my advisor, of something important, i.e. "Please be noted ...".

But I am wondering if there is any other way for notifying that is equally polite as "please be noted ..." but not too formal? (I am not sure of whether or not "please be noted ..." is too formal.)

Comment: 'Please note' not 'please be noted'… though that is not a reminder of something they were told earlier, it is to impart new information.

Comment: How about "please be informed..."?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I think it would be improper to remind your elder by saying something like "please note that the deadline is approaching"?

Comment: 'please be informed' is the same as 'please note' but sounds more like a lawyer telling a client something. Are you reminding him of something he should already know, or telling him something new?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Oh, not necessarily a specific thing. Just, for example, to remind my advisor of the deadline of submitting reference letters.

Comment: I think you may be trying to couch non-English formality in English; which is much harder to do. Tone of voice will convey your intent if you simply say "Did you remember that the deadline is Thursday…" or even "You remember…' or 'You know…' Bear in mind there's never a good way to try remind your boss of something he may have forgotten [unless that's specifically part of your job]. If he didn't forget it, he will be annoyed you thought he did; if he did forget it, he'll pretend he didn't :P

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thanks so much for understanding and pointing out my intention! Yep, I know, I just feel that sending such reminders (reasonable, say one email reminder sent three days before each deadline) are my obligation :)

Comment: then maybe start "Just to remind you...

Comment: "Please note that I'm a robot". :D How "friend" is this advisor to you? If you aren't that anxious about being formal to him, "just to remind you..." seems like the best option for me, just as @Tetsujin says.

Comment: I prefer something like "I know you are busy, but I was wondering if you had time to ... yet?"  If ... was not done yet, this would make it less likely to be perceived as that person's fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Could I just remind you that ......*

*May I take a moment of your time to remind you that .......*

*I hope you don't mind me contacting you to raise the date of (.........) which  is the deadline for submitting reference letters?*

*"Please be informed*" or "*Please note"* seem to me to be too formal and cold and at the same time not respectful enough.

Those would normally be used by a lawyer or government official.

You wish to address an elder/superior to remind them to do something for you so a bit of humility, respect, and a little warmth should provide you with a successful result.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have an additional question: What kind of titles for such an email would you suggest? Much appreciated :)

Comment: For such an email to your adviser I would simply put "Reference letter" in the subject line. I would then begin as follows: "With regard to the above subject, I hope you don't mind me contacting you......(as my third example previously submitted above).